# Map a word or phrase to a keyboard key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hotkeys, keymap

I want to map/assign a word or phrase to a keyboard key so I only have to tap the mapped key in stead of typing the entire word. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a software like [Phrase Express](http://www.phraseexpress.com/download.htm) to do so.